# Serving HTTPS images with Minio

Tags: https, storage, amazon-s3, minio

I followed this [documentation](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/integrations/generate-lets-encrypt-certificate-using-certbot-for-minio.html), but I can't make my images to be served with HTTPS.

I have the following `/etc/default/minio` configuration file:

```
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY="admin"
MINIO_VOLUMES="/usr/local/share/minio/"
MINIO_OPTS="-C /etc/minio --address vps.ovh.net:443 --console-address :9001"
MINIO_SECRET_KEY="secret"
```

If I specify another port like 9000 instead of 443, this time it works, but the file is served with HTTP:

http://vps.ovh.net:9000/images/product/e53b9fde-4df1-4e54-bef4-76cd8c97cdb2.jpg

I have generated the certificates in `/etc/minio` :

```
pwd
/etc/minio/certs
ll
rw------- 1 minio-user minio-user 1704 Feb  3 11:05 private.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 minio-user minio-user 5522 Feb  3 11:05 public.crt
```

Any ideas or tips?

Comment: I personally always use a reverse proxy in such scenarios. This way I have very similar TLS setup regardless of  software behind the reverse proxy. As an added bonus, some reverse proxies can manager TLS certs renewal automatically for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/integrations/generate-lets-encrypt-certificate-using-certbot-for-minio.html) you referenced advises placing the certificates under `${HOME}/.minio/certs` which is the default path. You have **not** followed the documentation, but placed them under the path `/etc/minio/certs`, instead.

If you wish to use that path, you would use `--certs-dir /etc/minio/certs` in your  `MINIO_OPTS`, as documented in both [Network Encryption (TLS)](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/network-encryption.html) (Default Path vs. Custom Path) & [MinIO Server `--certs-dir`, `-S`](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-server/minio-server.html#minio.server.-certs-dir).

It seems that with `-C /etc/minio` you have tried to do this using a **deprecated parameter**:

> **Important:**
>
> MinIO Server [RELEASE.2023-12-09T18-17-51Z](https://github.com/minio/minio/releases/tag/RELEASE.2023-12-09T18-17-51Z) removes the deprecated `--config-dir | -C` parameter. Deployments using this flag may start without TLS enabled. Replace those parameters with `--certs-dir | -S` and restart to re-enable TLS.

**That is exactly what happened.**

Comment: The documentation also lists the `-C` argument as deprecated.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Nice spot! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Right, in fact, I followed another tutorial at first which was partially outdated. Thanks! :)